# R; Time series analysis on sensor data

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, sensors, kalman-filter

I have a data frame of sensor data

I have a data frame as follows:

```
pressure    datetime
4.848374    2016-04-12 10:04:00   
4.683901    2016-04-12 10:04:32   
5.237860    2016-04-12 10:13:20
```

Now, I would like to apply `ARIMA` to make predictive analytics.

Since the data is not sampled uniformly, I have aggregated it on Hourly basis which looks as follows:

```
datetime                    pressure
"2016-04-19 00:00:00 BST"   5.581806
"2016-04-19 01:00:00 BST"   4.769832
"2016-04-19 02:00:00 BST"   4.769832  
"2016-04-19 03:00:00 BST"   4.553711  
"2016-04-19 04:00:00 BST"   6.285599  
"2016-04-19 05:00:00 BST"   5.873414
```

The pressure for every hour looks like below:

[image]

But I can't create `ts` object as I am not sure what the frequency should be for Hourly data.

Comment: I found this post on time series quite helpful in order to do this. 
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120806/frequency-value-for-seconds-minutes-intervals-data-in-r

Comment: Thanks. I came across the link but it did not solve, rather confused me more.

Comment: Since your data is aggregated to an hourly basis, the frequency = 24 for a day. Depends on if you have a year's week's or month's data.

Comment: When I do `sensor = ts(hourlyPressure, frequency = 24)`, the output has `Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(6, 24) 
Frequency = 24`, which I think is incorrect. How do I get accurate `start` and `end`

Comment: Why do you think that's wrong? You have 6 days worth of data, so your first record is the first hour of the first day (i.e. `c(1,1)`), and your last record is the 24th hour of the 6th day (i.e. `c(6, 24)`). Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you. I want to use `sensor` as an input for `ARIMA` but will it work as `sensor` does not contain actual timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has already been answered in the comment section, but just to reiterate, you should set the frequency to 24, as you want to forecast the hourly data:

```
sensor = ts(hourlyPressure, frequency = 24)
```

To your next point with regards to fixing the dates in your plot, lets start with some example data:

```
###Sequence of numbers to forecast    
hourlyPressure<-c(1:24, 12:36, 24:48, 36:60)
###Sequence of Accompanying Dates
dates<-seq(as.POSIXct("2016-04-19 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2016-04-23 02:00:00"), by="hour")
```

Now we can set the hourlyPressure data to be a ts() object (let's ignore the dates for a minute)

```
sensor <- ts(hourlyPressure, frequency=24)
```

Now fit your arima model, in this example I will use the auto.arima function from the forecast package as finding the best arima model is not the focus of attention here (although using auto.arima() is a pretty robust way of finding the best arima model to fit your data):

```
###fit arima model to sensor data
sensor_arima_fit<- auto.arima(sensor)
```

You can then plot this data with the appropriate dates by just specifying the x value in the plot() function

```
plot(y=sensor_arima_fit$x, x=dates)
```

A little more difficult is when we forecast our data and want to plot the original data, with the forecasts and have the dates correct.

```
###now forecast ahead (lets say 2 days) using the arima model that was fit above
forecast_sensor <- forecast(sensor_arima_fit, h = 48)
```

Now to plot the original data, forecasts with the correct dates, we can do the following:

```
###set h to be the same as above
h <- c(48)
###calculate the dates for the forecasted values
forecasted_dates<-seq(dates[length(dates)]+(60*60)*(1), 
                  dates[length(dates)]+(60*60)*(h), by="hour")

###now plot the data
plot(y=c(forecast_sensor$x, forecast_sensor$mean), 
     x=seq(as.POSIXct("2016-04-19 00:00:00"),as.POSIXct(forecasted_dates[length(forecasted_dates)]), by="hour"),
     xaxt="n", 
     type="l", 
     main="Plot of Original Series and Forecasts", 
     xlab="Date", 
     ylab="Pressure")

###correctly formatted x axis
axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(as.POSIXct("2016-04-19 00:00:00"), 
                       as.POSIXct(forecasted_dates[length(forecasted_dates)]), 
                       by="hour"), 
             format="%b %d", 
             tick = FALSE)
```

This plots the original data with the forecasts and the dates are correct. However, just like the forecast package provides, perhaps we want the forecasts to be in blue.

```
###keep same plot as before
plot(y=c(forecast_sensor$x, forecast_sensor$mean), 
     x=seq(as.POSIXct("2016-04-19 00:00:00"),as.POSIXct(forecasted_dates[length(forecasted_dates)]), by="hour"),
     xaxt="n", 
     type="l", 
     main="Plot of Original Series and Forecasts", 
     xlab="Date", 
     ylab="Pressure")

axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(as.POSIXct("2016-04-19 00:00:00"), 
                       as.POSIXct(forecasted_dates[length(forecasted_dates)]), 
                       by="hour"), 
             format="%b %d", 
             tick = FALSE)

###This time however, lets add a different color line for the forecasts
lines(y=forecast_sensor$mean, x= forecasted_dates, col="blue")
```